# how to reverse $event.stoppropogation() on button click of mat menu in angular 14

Tags: angular, stoppropagation

I implemented an angular application (@latest version), in my implementation I used a mat-menu to show some custom component which contains some customized options along with a apply button. By default, if we do any click in the menu popover screen immediately it will close. So I added a `stopPropagation` on my custom component to prevent closing popover action.

But I need to close the menu pop-over on apply button click event. But its failing because the `stopPropagation` in the parent level prevents the button close action.

How to escape from `stopPropagation` only for the specified button.

**File: app.component.html**

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <menu-toolbar  (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"></menu-toolbar>
</mat-menu>
```

**File: menu-toolbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './menu-toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './menu-toolbar.component.css' ]
})
export class MenuToolbarComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  applyChanges(): void {
    
    // some actions done

    console.log('Changes applied successfully...');
  }
}
```

**File: menu-toolbar.component.html**

```
<div>
    <mat-checkbox>Item #1</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox>Item #2</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox>Item #3</mat-checkbox>
</div>
<button mat-button (click)="applyChanges($event)">Apply</button>
```

please assist me how to escape from `stopPropagation` only for the "**Apply**" button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put matMenuTrigger.closeMenu() in click event, that worked for me.
`(click)="Submit(column.value,column.businessName);matMenuTrigger.closeMenu()"`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to your menu-toolbar the "matMenuTrigger". Then in "apply" function call to menuClose()

```
<!--see the #bt="matMenuTrigger"-->
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" 
         #bt="matMenuTrigger">Menu</button>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <menu-toolbar (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" [menuTrigger]="bt">
    </menu-toolbar>
</mat-menu>
```

In your menu-toolbar

```
import {MatMenuTrigger} from '@angular/material/menu'; 

  @Input('menuTrigger')menu:MatMenuTrigger
  applyChanges(event:any): void {
    this.menu.closeMenu()
    console.log("hi")
  }
```

NOTE: In general, a template reference variable applied to an html element is the own html element (in this case the button). It's the reason we use

```
#templateRefVariable="ExportClass"
```

Then our template reference variable makes reference to the "directive", so we can use all the methods of the directive. If you see the [docs about matMenuTrigger](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api) you see the "Exported as: matMenuTrigger"